# basics of chord learning in guitar

Tags: guitar, chords, technique, beginner

I am learning guitar of my own. I want to learn chords ,chord progression and strumming pattern. Can anyone suggest me in which order I should learn chords and how to easily remember them ??

Answer (score 4):

The simple chords that might be good to learn first are often called the '[cowboy chords](https://menga.net/cowboy-chords)' - so called because of their common use in country music.

I wouldn't particularly worry about what order to learn those in - rather, find some simple songs that contain just those chords, and learn the songs. That way, you'll learn how to move from one chord to another. many guitar learning resources will start with suggestions of such songs.

At some point, you'll need to learn how to do barre chords, but it's probably good to learn those simple shapes first. The most common barre chords are the same basic shape, but you have to find a comfortable way to base them on your index finger rather than the nut.

I think the best way to remember chords is not to try to *remember* them at all - instead, learn a couple of scales, and understand how the chords are built from the scales. You will easily be able to remember the shape of each chord by understanding what scale degrees it's built from.

Finally, I have a crazy theory that when it comes to simple chords, there are really only two basic shapes to learn - [here it is](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/43595/18896), but if you don't understand it, don't worry - I don't think anyone else did either!

Answer (score 3):

I help my guitar students learn the open chord shapes by actually referring to their shapes:

Big Triangle- G major

Little Triangle- D major, D7

Diagonal: C major, F major

Right Triangle- E major, A minor

Side by Side- A major, A7

Start playing songs straight away: the words 'kiss', 'horseradish' and 'opprobrium' aren't all that exciting until you use them in a sentence. It's the same with chords.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this or similar has been posed several times.

However - despite many books starting with key C, I advocate learning and using chords in 'family groups' in key E initially. Very often, a song will be made up using three chords. In a given key, they'll be the same three chords each time.

Starting with key E, the other two chords are A and B7. I choose these, as the changes between them are all in the same plane, and there are common notes which can be played with the same fingers and/or shape.

Then, add D, to make the family of A - A D and E. By now, the D has moved to a different hand angle, but you've improved, and it's only a small step. The go to key D - D G and A. All open chords. That's a start.

Another, perhaps even more important factor, while learning chords, is to try out different fingerings. Those shown on sites on the net may - or may not - be the best suited to you. And try to play some chords with a couple of different fingerings. Good reason being it's often easier to get from one specific to another with one fingering set, but to/from a different chord is easier with different fingering. Honest!

Comment: I searched for similar, and couldn't find anything quickly - if we do have existing similar questions, we may want to edit the titles to make them findable!

Answer (score 2):

1) **Learn these chords : C A G E D   or "Caged".**

Especially get the E and A down, but really all of them.

Learn a couple of songs using all these chords over your choices until your fingers can make the changes tolerably well. You can learn the F chord but that one is hard so don't fuss over it.

Practice and work at it. This is the hump for most people. It takes time and some discomfort on the fingertips at first.

"Gloria" by Shadows of the Knight works for this. E - D - A over and over.
Strumming will come with *practice and comfort doing chord changes*. Play songs you know and like so you have a feel for how it should sound. Get these chords and a couple of songs using them down.

**2) Learn how to play a barre chord using both the E chord shape and the D chord shape.** If you have really been working on your CAGED chords you will be ready.

**3) Understand how the E and A chord shapes you learned at the start can be used with the barre to play most any chord or progression you want.** In conjunction with the knowledge of the low string notes you can play just about any chord.

At that point you will be an accomplished guitar player. Many songs can be done with just these skills. Just do your thing and it will develop. Your understanding of the rest will follow.

I play "Gloria" all the time. Just to keep in practice.

"One chord [in a song] is rock and roll, two is ok, but three and your into jazz"  -- Lou Reed.

Comment: I have to disagree with this; learn useful chords at the very start. **B7** is not in your list; this is needed to play in the key of E which is so common in starter guitar music, and also one of the very first chords my first guitar teacher taught me. Choosing a system such as CAGED should come later.

Comment: In  3, did you mean learn barre E and barre **A** rather than D?

Comment: I just use CAGED as a simple way of remember the basic chords for a raw beginner.